# Recursive CTE and Count Info from recursive table

Tags: sql, database, recursion, common-table-expression

I have this table called `tblLandAreas`:

[image]

```
Level 1 = Bloq
Level 2 = Ships
Level 3 = Sides
Level 4 = Beds
```

`Ship` is a child of `Bloq`, `Sides` is a child of `Ship` and `Bed` is a child of `Side`.

And I need to show a report this way:

[image]

Only when `_parentid is null`

I have tried this but it is not working:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
DECLARE @t TABLE
    (
      ID INT ,
      ParentID INT ,
      Level INT
    )
INSERT  INTO @t
VALUES  ( 1, NULL, 1 ),
        ( 29, NULL, 1 ),
        ( 38, 29, 2 ),
        ( 32, 1, 2 ),
        ( 18, 1, 2 ),
        ( 41, 29, 2 ),
        ( 42, 41, 3 ),
        ( 43, 41, 3 ),
        ( 44, 41, 3 ),
        ( 45, 44, 4 )

;WITH cte AS(SELECT *, id AS baseid FROM @t WHERE ParentID IS NULL
             UNION ALL
             SELECT t.*, c.baseid FROM cte c JOIN @t t ON c.ID = t.ParentID)
SELECT baseid, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN Level = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) ships,
       SUM(CASE WHEN Level = 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) sides,
       SUM(CASE WHEN Level = 4 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) beds
FROM cte
WHERE ParentID IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY baseid
```

Output:

```
baseid  ships   sides   beds
1       2       0       0
29      2       3       1
```

To project on your structure:

```
;WITH Bloque AS(SELECT LandAreaId, _ParentId, _Level, LandAreaId AS baseLandAreaId
                FROM tblLandAreas WHERE _ParentId IS NULL
                UNION ALL
                SELECT a.LandAreaId, a._ParentId, a._Level, B.baseLandAreaId
                FROM Bloque B 
                JOIN tblLandAreas a ON B.LandAreaId = a._ParentId)
SELECT baseLandAreaId AS LandAreaId, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN _Level = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) [#Ships],
       SUM(CASE WHEN _Level = 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) [#Sides],
       SUM(CASE WHEN _Level = 4 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) [#Beds]
FROM Bloque
WHERE _ParentId IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY baseLandAreaId
```